# GAE InvalidArgumentException with Mail Service Error

Tags: php, email, google-app-engine

This is not a duplicate question I have tried a lot with GAE Php mail send but find exception below is not an authorized email address. I have tried with all email ids.

```
ot sendexception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Mail Service Error: Sender (info@mywebsite.in) is not an authorized email address.' in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/api/mail/BaseMessage.php:336 Stack trace: #0 /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/api/mail/Message.php(148): google\appengine\api\mail\BaseMessage->handleApplicationError(Object(google\appengine\runtime\ApplicationError)) #1 /base/data/home/apps/s~acuteservice-1260/1.393973634644018844/contact.php(38): google\appengine\api\mail\Message->send() #2 {main}
```

Below is my code that through above InvalidArgumentException

```
<?php
use google\appengine\api\mail\Message;

$name=$email=$query="";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){

   $name = $_POST["name"];
   $email = $_POST["email"];
   $query = $_POST["message"];

  require_once 'google/appengine/api/mail/Message.php';
    $mail_options = [
    "sender" => "info@mywebsite.in",
    "to" => "isashi4u@gmail.com",
    "subject" => "Subject",
    "textBody" => $query,
];

try {
    $message = new Message($mail_options);
    $message->send();
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    echo "not send";
    echo $e;
}

}?>
```

is there any way to give default setting on "sender" mail_option ?

Comment: `Sender (info@mywebsite.in) is not an authorized email address` seems clear enough. that address is not permitted to send through your google account.

Comment: How to add authorization email address ?

Comment: You will find an answer for that in here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/#sending_mail

Comment: Additionally you can use default sender account authorized for your application `"sender" => sprintf('Sender Name <%s@appspot.gserviceaccount.com>', AppIdentityService::getApplicationId())`